# How do I write $B$ as a linear combination of $E$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ be the bases of $\Bbb R^2$where  $B = \{v_1,v_2\}$ with $$v_1 = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1  
\\-2
\end{bmatrix}\right), v_2 = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
-3  
\\4 
\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ then we let E $$ E= 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0  
\\0&1&0&0&0  
\\0&0&1&0&0  
\\0&0&0&1&0  
\\0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ How do I write $B$ as a linear combination of $E$?

Comment: What is $E$ supposed to be in $R^2$ ?

Comment: The elements of a basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$ span all the elements (vectors) of $\mathbb{R^2}$; you should clarify what the $5 \times 5$-matrix $E$ is doing here...

Answer (score 1):

$B$ is a subset of $ \mathbb R^2$ and $E$ is the $5 \times 5$ -identity matrix.

So your question

"How do I write $B $ as a linear combination of $E$?

is very strange.